# Elasticsearch 2.2 cluster: adding node fails

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to add a second node. Therefore I have installed the same version of ES on another host in the same network (no firewall in-between the two).

The cluster name is the default on both hosts ("elasticsearch").

On node #2 I add the IP of the first node to elasticsearch.yml:

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["1.2.3.1"]
```

(also tried `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.1, "1.2.3.1"]`)

I shut down everything and first start node #1 and then node #2.

Node #1 gives me this soon after Node #2 comes up:

```
[2016-02-19 16:30:06,848][INFO ][rest.suppressed          ] /_bulk Params: {}
ClusterBlockException[blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/2/no master];]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlocks.globalBlockedException(ClusterBlocks.java:154)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlocks.globalBlockedRaiseException(ClusterBlocks.java:144)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportBulkAction.executeBulk(TransportBulkAction.java:212)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportBulkAction.doExecute(TransportBulkAction.java:159)
```

Node #2 gives me this upon issuing a `curl localhost:9200/_cat/health?pretty`:

```
[2016-02-19 16:30:45,177][INFO ][discovery.zen            ] [Zartra] failed to send join request to master [{Western Kid}{ymbhcgNQR6WrE-zdbrj3QQ}{172.31.32.37}{172.31.32.37:9300}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[Western Kid][172.31.32.37:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: IllegalStateException[Node [{Western Kid}{ymbhcgNQR6WrE-zdbrj3QQ}{172.31.32.37}{172.31.32.37:9300}] not master for join request]; ]
```

And I thought I read that putting up an ES cluster was the easiest thing in the world ;-)

Comment: Damn, I had set "network.host: 0.0.0.0" (to be able to access it from remote) in elasticsearch.yml on one node, but not the other. Setting the same thing on node #2 seems to have done the trick. No idea why though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the "network.host" configuration on the elasticsearch.yml ?

If you keep the default configuration, it will be set to "127.0.0.1".

Try to put `network.host: [_site_ , 127.0.0.1]`

Comment: Does that setting have an influence on the inter-node communication happening on port 9300?? I always thought this was for port 9200 only?

Comment: According to this documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/modules-network.html#advanced-network-settings) If you keep the default configuration. Nodes will never communicate with other service on the network. I think it will unlock communication for all ports